# Can a teleconverter make lenses designed for a "crop" sensor cover full frame?

Tags: optics, full-frame, sensor-size, teleconverter, image-circle

I have a crop lens. Can I fill a full-frame sensor adding an appropriate tele converter (focal length extender? Specifically, I have a 1/2" C-mount lens and terrible vignetting on a full frame camera. I assume, adding a 2X converter will double the actual image size thus filling the bigger sensor.

Comment: "I assume, adding a 2X converter will double the actual image size thus filling the bigger sensor." Why do you assume that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the effects of using a crop lens with a full frame sensor?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/60730/what-are-the-effects-of-using-a-crop-lens-with-a-full-frame-sensor)

Comment: @RomeoNinov The crux of this question is about the effect of the teleconverter, which is distinctly different from that question. I'm sure we'll have one somewhere though :-)

Comment: Yeah, it really helps to put the actual question in the title rather than a general topic. The latter is what tags are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use Canon 18-200 EF-s lens on Canon 6D full frame body?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39178/is-there-a-way-to-use-canon-18-200-ef-s-lens-on-canon-6d-full-frame-body)

Answer (score 6):

Your basic assumption about teleconverters is right. But you haven't done the math:

1/2" is 6.4mm x 4.8mm—doubled is still only 12.8mm x 9.6mm.

OTOH it's not unheard-of for tiny format lenses to have image circles well larger than their specification.